# If $f:[0,1] \to [0,1] $ is continuous, $f(0) =0 $, $f(1) = 1$, and $f^n(x) \triangleq f \ \circ \cdots \circ f(x) \equiv x $, then $f(x) \equiv x$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

If a mapping $f:[0,1] \to [0,1] $ is continuous, $f(0) =0 $, $f(1) = 1$, and $f^n(x) \triangleq f \ \circ \cdots \circ   f(x) \equiv x $, then $f(x) \equiv x$

The mapping $f$ is injective as $f(x) = f(y)$ implies $ x = f^n(x) =f^n(y) = y$. Thus $f$ is increasing.

For all $y$ in the interal $[f(0),f(1)]$, there is a unique $x_1$ such that $f(x_1) = y$. Assume that $x_1<y$; in this case $f(x_1) < f(y)$ and also $x_1 < f(x_1)$. Since $f$ is bijective, there is a unique $x_2$ such that $f(x_2) = x_1$.

We cannot have either $x_2 = x_1$ or $x_1 < x_2$. If the second case were true, then $f(x_1) < f(x_2) = x_1 < f(x_1)$.

Proceeding in this manner, we find a sequence of numbers $\{x_n\}$ such that $x_{n+1} < x_n$ and $f(x_{n+1}) = x_n$.

I wanted to use the nested interval principle but the intervals $[0,x_n]$ have not been shown to become arbitrarily small. Perhaps using a theorem on the sequence of numbers and the fact that $\{x_n\}$ has a limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose by contradiction and WLOG the existence of $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)<x_0$.

As you noticed, $f$ is a bijection, and has to be strictly increasing.

Therefore, iterating yields $f^n(x_0)<f^{n-1}(x_0)$, hence $x_0<f^{n-1}(x_0)$.

Consequently,by my initial assumption, $f(x_0)<f^{n-1}(x_0)$.

Applying $f$, $f^2(x_0)<x_0$.

Applying $f$ on the latest inequality yields $f^3(x_0)<f(x_0)$.

With my initial assumption this implies $f^3(x_0)<x_0$.

This goes on (by induction) to $f^n(x_0)<x_0$.

$$\text{Contradiction}$$

Comment: Though avoid using 'my'....